# CONCAT_WS in sequelize Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize and I am sort of converting raw queries written in PostgreSQL to ORM. Can someone help me with the following piece of query?

```
'array_agg(string_to_array(CONCAT_WS(' + "','" + ' , public."PollAnswers".answer_text, public."PollAnswers".vote_count,public."PollAnswers".id), ' + "','" + ')) AS answers
```

I am still unable to find array_agg, string_to_array and CONCAT_WS function or another way around in sequelize. I have been trying to find a solution from the last 6-7 hours and now it is becoming a frustration for me. Please guide me what should I do?

Thanks, it would be so much helpful.

Comment: The probably don't exist, as most of these functions are unique to Postgres.  So, you may either run a raw query, or find some other way to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen for giving a quick reply on the issue. So now I should think in a different way to find a quick and best solution? Is it a good practice to use ORM and raw queries side by side?

Comment: That's a really good question, and the answer is, ideally you wouldn't have to do this.  But, in reality, it will happen, maybe a little bit, hopefully not a lot.  Even if you use a raw query, make sure you use a prepared statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @TimBiegeleisen. This statement would really help me a lot to think in a different direction. (y)